# What are the differences between the HuffYUV and ffvhuff codecs in FFmpeg?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-conversion, codec, video-encoding

Doing `ffmpeg -codecs | grep -i huffyuv` shows that my FFmpeg build supports three different versions of the HuffYUV lossless video codec:

```
DEVI.S ffvhuff              Huffyuv FFmpeg variant
DEVI.S huffyuv              HuffYUV
D.VI.S hymt                 HuffYUV MT
```

I understand that HuffYUV MT is multi-threaded, and that my build only seems to support decoding it, but what are the differences between the standard `HuffYUV` codec and `ffvhuff`, FFmpeg's version of it? Is this documented anywhere?

Comment: [COMPARISON OF LOSSLESS VIDEO CODECS FOR CROWD-BASED QUALITY ASSESSMENT ON TABLETS](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.1038.6469&rep=rep1&type=pdf) (pdf) explains the differences. If that answers your question let me know and I will write up an answer tomorrow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On the `ffmpeg` encoding side of things there are two main differences.

## Pixel formats

ffvhuff supports many more pixel formats (44 vs 3).

Refer to `ffmpeg -h encoder=ffvhuff` and `ffmpeg -h encoder=huffyuv` for the list of supported pixel formats for each encoder.

## Per-frame Huffman tables

ffvhuff supports per-frame (context-adaptive) Huffman tables which can result in a smaller output file size. But it is slower to encode because it forces the thread count to 1.

Default is **not** to use per-frame Huffman tables. It can be enabled with `-context 1`.

**Other than pixel formats and per-frame Huffman tables they are pretty much identical.**

Comment: *It forces the thread count to 1* - does this mean that `ffvhuff` is multithreaded by default?

Comment: @Prometheus Yes, both ffvhuff and huffyuv are. See `Threading capabilities` in `ffmpeg -h encoder=foo`

Comment: My bad, I missed that line in the output.

Comment: @Prometheus I haven't used these encoders for years. Typically for me: ffv1 for archival, utvideo for temporary lossless intermediates if i have to edit in Premiere, and lossless H.264 via libx264 for everything else.

Comment: Yeah, I've since considered Lagarith (not supported for encoding in FFmpeg), Utvideo and FFV1 as alternatives. I was looking into HuffYUV and similar initially because the people over at VideoHelp and DigitalFAQ swear by them for VHS captures, but the output files are still much bigger compared to a more modern codec.

Comment: @Prometheus ...to clarify my previous comment those are the encoders I use when making lossless outputs. The professional digital archival community have adopted FFV1 + FLAC in Matroska, so that is what I would recommend for any archival work. Otherwise, if you're just digitizing VHS for consumer level usage then regular, lossy H.264 is what I provide (occasionally HEVC).

Comment: As far as I've been able to gather so far from the forums (not yet got my hands on the necessary hardware), the problem with VHS is that it's often more tape restoration than it is capture, so the lossless files need to be used as intermediate files which are then fed into more advanced Avisynth filters like QTGMC for deinterlacing, denoising and the like.

Answer (score 4):

#### What are the differences between the HuffYUV and ffvhuff codecs?

**HuffYUV**

> HuffYUV was proposed by Ben Rudiak-Gould as an alternative to
> uncompressed Y CbCr video. It combines an intra-frame prediction with
> a consecutive Huffman entropy coding of the residuals. The intra-frame
> prediction selects between three different prediction models: left,
> gradient and median.
>
> - The first model, left, only uses the pixel l to predict the pixel x as x = l,
> - the second model, gradient, predicts x as x = l + a -d and
> - the median model selects the median value from the model left, the model gradient and from the pixel a above x
>
> Note, that the model selection is not adaptive, but rather one model
> is selected a-priori to the encoding and then used for the complete
> video sequence. Also only a fixed table for the Huffmann code entropy
> encoding is used.

Added for context:

> FFvYUV is an extension of HuffYUV developed by the FFmpeg project to address some of HuffYUV’s short-comings: instead of a fixed Huffman table, context-adaptive Huffman tables are used for the entropy encoding.

Source [COMPARISON OF LOSSLESS VIDEO CODECS FOR CROWD-BASED QUALITY ASSESSMENT ON TABLETS](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.1038.6469&rep=rep1&type=pdf) (pdf) authored by Christian Keimel, Christopher Pangerl and Klaus Diepold.

The paper linked above includes a lot more information, images, and links to further resources.

---

**ffvhuff**

This codec was developed by ffmpeg.

> It is a huffyuv like codec except it is not backwards compatible with huffyuv. However, it compresses better than huffyuv, supports yv12 colorspace, and is about as fast as huffyuv

Source [ffvhuff? [Archive] - Doom9's Forum](https://forum.doom9.org/archive/index.php/t-96095.html)

Comment: A good quote from the linked article, *"FFvYUV[15] is an extension of HuffYUV developed by the FFmpeg project to address some of HuffYUV’s short-comings: instead of a fixed Huffman table, context-adaptive Huffman tables are used for the entropy encoding."*

Comment: Ah missed that, although it is not specifically about ffvhuff which the OP asked about, it does provide some useful context.. Adding to the answer. Thanks.

Comment: It's a shame that there's no official documentation about `ffvhuff`, an open-source codec developed by an open-source project, and that the only real information on it comes from third-party benchmarks and forums.

Comment: @llogan Is `FFvYUV` a different thing to `ffvhuff`, or are they being used interchangeably there?

Comment: @Prometheus I assumed it was a typo. To some developers the code is the documentation. For others coding is more fun that writing documentation.

Comment: @llogan That would make sense, I've seen no other reference to anything called FFvYUV anywhere.